# LWJGL - not all display lists rendering

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm working on a Minecraft like game. I create display list for each *16x16x16* chunk. It works fine. But when I'm trying to add block selection it's invisible. It appears only when I'm at some random positions(I render selection at 0, 0, 0) . I have no idea what is wrong.

My render loop:

```
while (isRunning) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    timer.nextFrame();
    input(timer.getDelta());

    tex.bind();
    glLoadIdentity();

    renderChunks();

    renderText();
    renderSelection();

    Display.update();
    errorCheck();
    if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

renderChunks:

```
glRotated(player.getRy(), 1, 0, 0);
glRotated(player.getRx(), 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-player.getX(), -player.getY(), -player.getZ());
//---------
for (int x = minWorldChunkX; x < maxWorldChunkX; ++x) {
    for (int y = minWorldChunkY; y < maxWorldChunkY; ++y) {
        for (int z = minWorldChunkZ; z < maxWorldChunkZ; ++z) {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x << 4, y << 4, z << 4);
        glCallList(chunkDisplayLists.get(new ChunkPosition(x, y, z)));
        glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

renderSelection:

```
glPushMatrix();
glCallList(selectionDisplayList);
glPopMatrix();
```

selection display list:

```
selectionDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(selectionDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
glLineWidth(3);

glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);

glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);

glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);

glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);



glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);

glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);

glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);

glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);


glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);

glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);

glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);

glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
glEnd();
glEndList();
```

Source code is avaible on my [github](https://github.com/Barteks2x/FREEMine)

EDIT:
When I moved renderSelection() from render loop to renderChunks() before rendering chunks it worked. But when I change renderSelection() to:

```
glPushMatrix();
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glCallList(selectionDisplayList);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPopMatrix();
```

It disappears completely.

EDIT 2:
Disabling blending while rendering selection fixed it.

[screenshos](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54602353/screenshot.tar)

Comment: Perhaps you could include a snippet of the code you think is problematic?

Comment: If it is fixed, please answer your own question to let others know they don't have to read all that for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling blending while rendering block selection fixed it.

New renderSelection code:

```
glPushMatrix();
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glCallList(selectionDisplayList);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glPopMatrix();
```

UPDATE: It wan actually caused by something else:

```
selectionDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(selectionDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
...
glLineWidth(3);//This is what caused the issue
...
```

Normally setting line width between glBegin() and glEnd() should cause error, but it did not on my computer (ATI graphics card, Ubuntu). On other computer glError() returned non-zero value.